# Wpf Storyboard привязка к To для указания цвета

Tags: wpf, usercontrol

У меня есть анимация для usercontrol  мне нужно сделать привязку к To, ниже код который я пробовал. Он выдает ошибку: "Не удается зафиксировать данное дерево шкалы времени Storyboard для использования в различных потоках." Заранее спасибо

```
 <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="arrow">
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                         To="{StaticResource ColorBackground_MouseOver_ComboBoxArrowAnimation}" Duration="0:0:00.01" />
                                            <ColorAnimation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                         To="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomComboBox}}, Path=BorderBrush_MouseOver_CustomComboBox2}"
                                                             Duration="0:0:00.300" />
                                        </Storyboard>
```

Код c# для usercontrol

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BorderBrush_MouseOver_CustomComboBoxProperty2 = DependencyProperty.Register(
     "BorderBrush_MouseOver_CustomComboBox2", typeof(Color), typeof(CustomComboBox));


  

         /// <summary>
        /// Цвет при нажатии\подстветки\анимации BorderBrush у кнопки
        /// </summary>
        public Color BorderBrush_MouseOver_CustomComboBox2
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(BorderBrush_MouseOver_CustomComboBoxProperty2); }
            set { SetValue(BorderBrush_MouseOver_CustomComboBoxProperty2, value); }
        }
```